# Merging only one column on matching rows

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I have duplicate records(rows). Typically I have 2 rows per record and I need one. The rows are identical apart from one column. Is there a way to merge duplicate rows based on their ID in Column A but only merge column D

Column B for example as the same number, I don't want to merge this column as it will provide the wrong figure as column D has different words per row.

Data is currently.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C     Column D    Column E    Column F
178924      £125        £895         Card         82         92
178924      £125        £895         Stamp        82         92
178927      £11         £85          Card         52         69
178927      £11         £85          Stamp        52         69
```

Perfect result would be

```
Column A    Column B    Column C     Column D    Column E    Column F
178924      £125        £895         Card, Stamp  82         92
178927      £11         £85          Card, Stamp  52         69
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data and what you want the end result to be, as it is not always easy to imagine just from the words.

Comment: A data sample and the expected result are essential if you want an answer. Please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: Thank you both. I have added an example of the data as it stands and ideal outcome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following formula in Column G

```
=$D1 & ", " & VLOOKUP($A1, $A2:$D6, 4, FALSE)
```

Where your data is entered into `A1`.

This will return `#N/A` for unmatched records (you can use `IFERROR` to mask this with something else if you require) and a concatenation of Column D as in your expected output for matched records. You can filter the results to remove the unmatched to display your desired result.

This solution only works for the first instance of your ID (assuming only 2 instances of each ID in your question). If you want to delete unmatched rows you would have to use VBA.